# Can't link C++ project with openssl static libraries

Tags: c++, cross-compiling

I have some project done on C++ and I need to compile it for Windows XP and later.

This is the header file of my `RsaEncryptor` class (I think it is no matter to post sources here, because I'm sure on 100% that it works fine, but if it is required I can do it):

```
#ifndef RSAENCRYPTOR_H_
#define RSAENCRYPTOR_H_

#include <stdexcept>
#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/engine.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>

// One of this paddings can be used
//#define PADDING RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING
#define PADDING RSA_PKCS1_PADDING
//#define PADDING RSA_NO_PADDING

class RsaEncryptor {

private:

    RSA* publicKey;
    RSA* privateKey;

public:

    RsaEncryptor() {
        publicKey = nullptr;
        privateKey = nullptr;
    }

    ~RsaEncryptor() {
        if ( this->publicKey )
            RSA_free( this->publicKey );
        if ( this->privateKey )
            RSA_free( this->privateKey );
    }

    size_t GetCipherBytesCount() {
        return 172; //is default for 1024 bit key length
    }

    void SetPublicKeyFromString(const std::string& content);
    void SetPrivateKeyFromString(const std::string& content);

    std::string Encrypt(const std::string& plainData);
    std::string Decrypt(const std::string& cipherData);

};


#endif /* RSAENCRYPTOR_H_ */
```

I use latest version of `Eclipse Neon` for C++ development on `Windows 10 x64` machine.

Also I have read [this](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation#Configure_Options):

> (...) you will need to configure with `no-async` when building OpenSSL 1.1.0 and above for Windows XP or Vista

And I was guided by [following](https://marc.xn--wckerlin-0za.ch/computer/cross-compile-openssl-for-windows-on-linux) instructions.

What did I do:

1. install `Ubuntu 17.04 x64` inside Virtual Box under `Windows 10 x64`.
2. download latest version of OpenSSL library from `Ubuntu`
3. install [mxe](http://mxe.cc/) and all requirements (but can't compile with it and I decide to use `mingw32`)
4. install `mingw32` via `root@user-pc:/home/user# apt-get install gcc-mingw-w64-i686`
5. unpack OpenSSL library in `/home/user/openssl-x32`
6. go to `/home/user/openssl-x32`
7. run `./Configure mingw --cross-compile-prefix=i686-w64-mingw32 --prefix=/home/user/builds/openssl-x32-static no-shared no-async`
8. run `make`
9. run `make install`
10. copy `libssl.a` and `libcrypto.a` from `/home/user/builds/openssl-x32-static/lib` to host machine (`Windows 10 x64`) to folder `E:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\`
11. copy `include` directory from `Ubuntu` to host machine in folder `E:\MyProjects\my-app\include`
12. Add `libraries` folder to linker configurations
13. Add `include` folder to compiler configurations
14. Then, I build my project and got following answer:

> 11:58:09 **** Rebuild of configuration Debug for project app ****
>   Info: Configuration "Debug" uses tool-chain "MinGW GCC" that is
>   unsupported on this system, attempting to build anyway. Info: Internal
>   Builder is used for build g++
>   "-IC:\MyProjects\my-app\include" -O0 -g3
>   -Wall -c -std=c++11 -m32 -o RsaEncryptor.o "..\RsaEncryptor.cpp"  g++ "-IC:\MyProjects\my-app\include" -O0 -g3
>   -Wall -c -std=c++11 -m32 -o main.o "..\main.cpp"  In file included from ..\main.cpp:5:0: ..\FilesFinder.h: In member function 'void
>   FilesFinder::FindRecursively(const string&, const FilesFilter&)':
>   ..\FilesFinder.h:90:56: warning: comparison between signed and
>   unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
>         while (destinationContainer.GetElementsCount() >= MAX_ELEMENTS_COUNT) {
>                                                           ^ g++ "-IC:\MyProjects\my-app\include" -O0 -g3
>   -Wall -c -std=c++11 -m32 -o aes256.o "..\aes256.cpp"  g++ "-LC:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries"
>   -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++ -static -lpthread -m32 -o C:/MyProjects/my-app/bin/Debug/app
>   RsaEncryptor.o aes256.o main.o -lssl -lcrypto -lgdi32 
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_addr.o):b_addr.c:(.text+0xaa):
>   undefined reference to `_imp__getnameinfo@28'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_addr.o):b_addr.c:(.text+0xe0):
>   undefined reference to`_imp__ntohs@4'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_addr.o):b_addr.c:(.text+0x242):
>   undefined reference to `gai_strerrorW'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_addr.o):b_addr.c:(.text+0x820):
>   undefined reference to`_imp__freeaddrinfo@4'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_addr.o):b_addr.c:(.text+0xb5d):
>   undefined reference to `_imp__getaddrinfo@16'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_addr.o):b_addr.c:(.text+0xba2):
>   undefined reference to`gai_strerrorW'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock.o):b_sock.c:(.text+0xd7):
>   undefined reference to `_imp__WSAStartup@8'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock.o):b_sock.c:(.text+0xe8):
>   undefined reference to`_imp__WSAGetLastError@0'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock.o):b_sock.c:(.text+0x2c7):
>   undefined reference to `_imp__WSAStartup@8'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock.o):b_sock.c:(.text+0x2d8):
>   undefined reference to`_imp__WSAGetLastError@0'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock.o):b_sock.c:(.text+0x3b1):
>   undefined reference to `_imp__ntohs@4'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock.o):b_sock.c:(.text+0x40c):
>   undefined reference to`_imp__getsockopt@20'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock.o):b_sock.c:(.text+0x423):
>   undefined reference to `_imp__WSAGetLastError@0'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock.o):b_sock.c:(.text+0x43c):
>   undefined reference to`_imp__gethostbyname@4'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock.o):b_sock.c:(.text+0x48b):
>   undefined reference to `_imp__WSAStartup@8'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock.o):b_sock.c:(.text+0x4a2):
>   undefined reference to`_imp__WSAGetLastError@0'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock.o):b_sock.c:(.text+0x52c):
>   undefined reference to `_imp__WSACleanup@0'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock.o):b_sock.c:(.text+0x54d):
>   undefined reference to`_imp__ioctlsocket@12'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock.o):b_sock.c:(.text+0x563):
>   undefined reference to `_imp__WSAGetLastError@0'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock.o):b_sock.c:(.text+0x6b7):
>   undefined reference to`_imp__WSAStartup@8'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock.o):b_sock.c:(.text+0x6c8):
>   undefined reference to `_imp__WSAGetLastError@0'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock.o):b_sock.c:(.text+0x942):
>   undefined reference to`_imp__WSAGetLastError@0'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock.o):b_sock.c:(.text+0x9dc):
>   undefined reference to `_imp__setsockopt@20'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock.o):b_sock.c:(.text+0xa15):
>   undefined reference to`_imp__ioctlsocket@12'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock.o):b_sock.c:(.text+0xa32):
>   undefined reference to `_imp__WSAGetLastError@0'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock.o):b_sock.c:(.text+0xaa6):
>   undefined reference to`_imp__getsockname@12'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock.o):b_sock.c:(.text+0xb22):
>   undefined reference to `_imp__WSAGetLastError@0'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock2.o):b_sock2.c:(.text+0x27):
>   undefined reference to`_imp__socket@12'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock2.o):b_sock2.c:(.text+0x4e):
>   undefined reference to `_imp__WSAGetLastError@0'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock2.o):b_sock2.c:(.text+0x120):
>   undefined reference to`_imp__setsockopt@20'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock2.o):b_sock2.c:(.text+0x15b):
>   undefined reference to `_imp__connect@12'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock2.o):b_sock2.c:(.text+0x1f5):
>   undefined reference to`_imp__setsockopt@20'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock2.o):b_sock2.c:(.text+0x206):
>   undefined reference to `_imp__WSAGetLastError@0'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock2.o):b_sock2.c:(.text+0x265):
>   undefined reference to`_imp__WSAGetLastError@0'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock2.o):b_sock2.c:(.text+0x2c6):
>   undefined reference to `_imp__WSAGetLastError@0'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock2.o):b_sock2.c:(.text+0x377):
>   undefined reference to`_imp__getsockopt@20'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock2.o):b_sock2.c:(.text+0x38f):
>   undefined reference to `_imp__WSAGetLastError@0'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock2.o):b_sock2.c:(.text+0x4a7):
>   undefined reference to`_imp__setsockopt@20'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock2.o):b_sock2.c:(.text+0x4b4):
>   undefined reference to `_imp__WSAGetLastError@0'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock2.o):b_sock2.c:(.text+0x53a):
>   undefined reference to`_imp__bind@12'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock2.o):b_sock2.c:(.text+0x55f):
>   undefined reference to `_imp__listen@8'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock2.o):b_sock2.c:(.text+0x5a5):
>   undefined reference to`_imp__setsockopt@20'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock2.o):b_sock2.c:(.text+0x5b6):
>   undefined reference to `_imp__WSAGetLastError@0'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock2.o):b_sock2.c:(.text+0x63a):
>   undefined reference to`_imp__setsockopt@20'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock2.o):b_sock2.c:(.text+0x64b):
>   undefined reference to `_imp__WSAGetLastError@0'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock2.o):b_sock2.c:(.text+0x6b2):
>   undefined reference to`_imp__WSAGetLastError@0'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock2.o):b_sock2.c:(.text+0x713):
>   undefined reference to `_imp__WSAGetLastError@0'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock2.o):b_sock2.c:(.text+0x7a6):
>   undefined reference to`_imp__accept@12'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock2.o):b_sock2.c:(.text+0x7e7):
>   undefined reference to `_imp__WSAGetLastError@0'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock2.o):b_sock2.c:(.text+0x84b):
>   undefined reference to`_imp__closesocket@4'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(b_sock2.o):b_sock2.c:(.text+0x86c):
>   undefined reference to `_imp__closesocket@4'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(bss_sock.o):bss_sock.c:(.text+0x1b1):
>   undefined reference to`_imp__WSASetLastError@4'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(bss_sock.o):bss_sock.c:(.text+0x1d0):
>   undefined reference to `_imp__send@16'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(bss_sock.o):bss_sock.c:(.text+0x20a):
>   undefined reference to`_imp__WSAGetLastError@0'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(bss_sock.o):bss_sock.c:(.text+0x272):
>   undefined reference to `_imp__WSASetLastError@4'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(bss_sock.o):bss_sock.c:(.text+0x299):
>   undefined reference to`_imp__send@16'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(bss_sock.o):bss_sock.c:(.text+0x2ca):
>   undefined reference to `_imp__WSAGetLastError@0'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(bss_sock.o):bss_sock.c:(.text+0x33d):
>   undefined reference to`_imp__WSASetLastError@4'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(bss_sock.o):bss_sock.c:(.text+0x360):
>   undefined reference to `_imp__recv@16'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(bss_sock.o):bss_sock.c:(.text+0x39a):
>   undefined reference to`_imp__WSAGetLastError@0'
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(bss_sock.o):bss_sock.c:(.text+0x457):
>   undefined reference to `_imp__WSAGetLastError@0'
>   c:/programs/mingw_w64_mingw32_gcc_stdthread_win32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   C:\MyProjects\my-app\libraries\libcrypto.a(bss_sock.o):
>   bad reloc address 0x24 in section`.rdata'
>   c:/programs/mingw_w64_mingw32_gcc_stdthread_win32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe:
>   final link failed: Invalid operation collect2.exe: error: ld returned
>   1 exit status
>
> 11:58:21 Build Finished (took 11s.567ms)

I need just link my completed C++ project with correct-compiled (with flag `no-async`) OpenSSL library to let it work under old versions of Windows.

I will be happy to get any help with this issue.

Comment: You have tagged C *and* C++. they are different languages. You should only tag the language for which you require answers. Going by your question I'm assuming you want C++ answers so I have removed the C tag for you this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most if not all of the undefined symbols in your error log come from Winsock. Try linking with `-lws2_32`.

Comment: Yes, you were right: I link it with flags `-lssl -lcrypto -lcrypt32 -lgdi32 -lws2_32` and it linked successfully! But I test my application again (under Windows XP), and it still not works... :(